# MVC3 - Reading Controller Authentication Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am populating a MVC3 navigation menu and I want to read my controller defined authentication  roles for each of my SiteMap nodes.....is there a means to do so without using Reflection ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MVC SiteMap Provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) to generate your menu. It has built in security trimming based on `AuthrizeAttribute`. You can extend it easily.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I wanted, but no where in there documentation could I find this, thanks for saving me a headache!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this in your view (Razor sintax):

```
@if(User.IsInRole("role_name") {
    @* Show or not show the item depending on the user's role *@
}
```

Just change de `@` for `<% %>` if you're using the WebFormsViewEngine instead of the RazorViewEngine.

The same works in your controller, by the way:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("role_name") 
    { }
}
```

Comment: I was more interesting in enumerating the Controllers....rather than checking a user's roles within a View.  I was hoping to avoid using the CodePlex Sitemap provider.....I am currently using the Telerik MVC Extensions for this menu security trimming at the present.

I was hoping that MVC3 may have this functionality by now.

Answer (score 0):

I was more interesting in enumerating the Controllers....rather than checking a user's roles within a View.  I was hoping to avoid using the CodePlex Sitemap provider.....I am currently using the Telerik MVC Extensions for this menu security trimming at the present.

I was hoping that MVC3 may have this functionality by now.